# How to interact with the Wordpress JSON API using PhP?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api, wordpress-json-api

I'm trying to create a PhP script that will automatically post an article on my wordpress website (I'm using the wordpress CMS, it's not a wordpress.com website).

Here is what I've done so far:

### Plugin installations

I've installed and activated the WordPress JSON API and the Basic Auth plugins on my website.

### Library and code

I've downloaded the [WP REST php Library](https://github.com/Automattic/wp-rest-php-lib/tree/master) and I've uploaded the files in src in the same folder as my script.

Here is the code of my php script:

```
require_once( 'class-wp-rest-client.php' );
require_once( 'class-wp-rest-request.php' );
require_once( 'class-wp-rest-exception.php' );
require_once( 'class-wp-rest-transport.php' );
require_once( 'class-wp-rest-transport-curl.php' );
require_once( 'class-wp-rest-transport-wp-http-api.php' );
require_once( 'class-wp-rest-object.php' );
require_once( 'class-wpapi-rest-object-post.php' );
require_once( 'class-wpapi-rest-object-posts.php' );
require_once( 'class-wpapi-rest-client.php' );


use WP_REST_Client;
use WP_REST_Request;
use WP_REST_Object;
use WP_REST_Exception;
use WP_REST_Transport;
use WP_REST_Transport_WP_HTTP_API;
use WP_REST_Transport_Curl;
use WPAPI_REST_Object_Post;
use WPAPI_REST_Object_Posts;
use WPAPI_REST_Basic_Auth_Client;


$post_data=array(
            'title' => 'New Post',
            'content_raw' => 'This is a test'
        );



$wp_api_client = new WPAPI_REST_Basic_Auth_Client( 'http://example.com', 'login', 'password' );

if ($wp_api_client) echo "connected";

try {

$current_post = WPAPI_REST_Object_Post::initWithId( 1, $wp_api_client );
$current_post_data = $current_post->get();
echo 'Post Title:' . $current_post_data->ID;    

} catch ( WP_REST_Exception $e ) { print_r($e); }

?>
```

And I'm getting this error:

> WP_REST_Exception Object ( [message:protected] => HTTP error for request; response:

I'm not sure if the error is coming from me not using the library properly or else. Anyone can help me with this?

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those having the same issue, it seems that it is the Basic Auth plugin that is not working.

For a better working API, connect your site with JetPack to Wordpress.com and use their API.

Cheers,
Arthur